# Finding Unique Items in a Go Slice or Array

Tags: arrays, go, set, unique, slice

I'm pretty new to go and I'm really, really confused right now.

Let's say I have a list of coordinates and lets say I have some doubles in this list of coordinates. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make a unique list. Normally in Python I can "cheat" with sets and other built-ins. Not so much in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type visit struct {
    x, y int
}

func main() {
    var visited []visit
    var unique []visit

    visited = append(visited, visit{1, 100})
    visited = append(visited, visit{2, 2})
    visited = append(visited, visit{1, 100})
    visited = append(visited, visit{1, 1})

    unique = append(unique, visit{1, 1})

    fmt.Println(unique)

    // Go through the visits and find the unique elements
    for _, v := range visited {
        for _, u := range unique {

            fmt.Printf("Here's unique: %v\n", unique)
            fmt.Printf("Comparing %v to %v is %v\n", v, u, reflect.DeepEqual(v, u))

            if reflect.DeepEqual(v, u) {
                fmt.Println("Skip")
            } else {
                unique = append(unique, v)
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(unique)
}
```

<kbd>[Run it on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7lYjfSaBP0)</kbd>

Comment: You can typically do something like `map[string]struct{}{}` if you want a list to only contain unique entries. An empty struct doesn't take up any memory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. The most serious is that since you're comparing each specific element of the `visited` slice to **all** of the elements of `unique`, you will end up appending it if `unique` contains at least one which is different. And going forward, you will end up appending it multiple times if there are more elements in `unique` which differ as your inner `for` loop doesn't "break". This is not what you want, you want to append elements which equals to **none** of `unique`.

Also note that a `struct` in Go is comparable if each of its fields are comparable. Since your `visit` struct contains only 2 `int` fields, it is comparable and so you can compare values of `visit` type simply with the `==` operator, no need that ugly `reflect.DeepEqual()`. See [Spec: Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.

Here's a simplified, correct version that applies your logic:

```
visited := []visit{
    visit{1, 100},
    visit{2, 2},
    visit{1, 100},
    visit{1, 1},
}
var unique []visit

for _, v := range visited {
    skip := false
    for _, u := range unique {
        if v == u {
            skip = true
            break
        }
    }
    if !skip {
        unique = append(unique, v)
    }
}

fmt.Println(unique)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/yXpLNvx0m0)):

```
[{1 100} {2 2} {1 1}]
```

#### Alternative

It's true that Go doesn't have a built-in set type, but you can use a `map[visit]bool` easily as a set. With that, it becomes really simple! Note that `visit` can be used as key in the map because it is comparable (see above).

```
visited := []visit{
    visit{1, 100},
    visit{2, 2},
    visit{1, 100},
    visit{1, 1},
}
unique := map[visit]bool{}

for _, v := range visited {
    unique[v] = true
}

fmt.Println(unique)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MT-da7OU0V)):

```
map[{2 2}:true {1 1}:true {1 100}:true]
```

The unique "list" is the list of keys in the map.

If you want the unique `visit` values as a slice, see this variant:

```
var unique []visit
m := map[visit]bool{}

for _, v := range visited {
    if !m[v] {
        m[v] = true
        unique = append(unique, v)
    }
}

fmt.Println(unique)
```

Output (as expected, try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/A6l6DW6LM1)):

```
[{1 100} {2 2} {1 1}]
```

Note that this index expression: `m[v]` evaluates to `true` if `v` is already in the map (as a key, `true` is the value we stored in the map). If `v` is not yet in the map, `m[v]` yields the zero value of the value type which is `false` for the type `bool`, properly telling that the value `v` is not yet in the map. See [Spec: Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions):

> For a of [map type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) `M`:
>
> ...if the map is `nil` or does not contain such an entry, `a[x]` is the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for the value type of `M`

Comment: Thanks you so much for the guidance, feedback and revision. Like I said, I'm new to Go. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use help of Map to solve this puzzle

https://play.golang.org/p/b7JtHYQ3N8

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type visit struct {
    x, y int
}

func main() {
    var visited []visit
    var unique []visit

    uniqueMap := map[visit]int{}

    visited = append(visited, visit{1, 100})
    visited = append(visited, visit{2, 2})
    visited = append(visited, visit{1, 100})
    visited = append(visited, visit{1, 1})

    for _, v := range visited {
        if _, exist := uniqueMap[v]; !exist {
            uniqueMap[v] = 1
            unique = append(unique, v)
        } else {
            uniqueMap[v]++
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Uniques: %v\nMaps:%v\n", unique, uniqueMap)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you can make a [map](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) of visits.
Something like this

```
visited := make(map[visit]Boolean)
```

than you can set the value of the visited.

```
visited[visit]=true
```

and lastly, you can fetch all visited locations by this code

```
for k, _ := range visited {
    unique = append(unique, k)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your slice via [`sort.Slice()`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Slice) and then make the slice unique by overwriting non-unique elements with following unique ones:

```
func Unique[T comparable](xs []T) []T {
    n := len(xs)
    if n == 0 {
        return xs
    }
    j := 0
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        if xs[j] !=  xs[i] {
            j++
            if j < i {
                xs[j] = xs[i]
                for k := i + 1; k < n; k++ {
                    if xs[j] !=  xs[k] {
                        j++
                        xs[j] = xs[k]
                    }
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
    xs = xs[0:j+1]
    return xs
}
```

Making the slice unique is only linear effort, however, this is dominated by the sorting (unless your input already is sorted), which is in `O(n log n)`.

Example usage:

```
visited = sort.Slice(visited, func(i, j int) bool {
        return visited[i].x < visited[j].x && visited[i].y < visited[j].y })
visited = Unique(visited)
unique := visited
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to sort or don't care about the element order you can store all elements in a set-like map, which eliminates duplicates.

Example:

```
h := map[visit]struct{} {}
for _, v := range visited {
    h[v] = struct{} {}
}
unique := make(visit[], len(h))
i := 0
for k := range h {
    unique[i] = k
    i++
}
```

The total runtime is linear, unless your data hashes badly.

Comment: Since Go 1.18 there is also [`slices.Compact()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286206/427158) which works like Unique.