# How to finding result of intercept of two slices in golang

Tags: arrays, go, intercept

There is two slices in string type.I want to finding intercept result in set from the two slices in golang.I want to find the best solution rather than iterating each slice.

```
first_slice := []string{"F8-E7-1E-14-AE-00", "F8-E7-1E-14-D0-30", "84-18-3A-2F-05-E0","84-18-3A-2F-05-E8" } 
second_slice := []string{"F8-E7-1E-14-D0-30", "84-18-3A-2F-05-E8","F8-E7-1E-54-AE-08"}


Output:
    result_slice := []string{"F8-E7-1E-14-D0-30", "84-18-3A-2F-05-E8"}
```

I have use following  approaches but it is not best approaches for large data set.

```
var result_slice *[]string

for _, i := range first_slice {
    for _, x := range second_slice {
        if i == x {
            &result_slice.append(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate if give me good solution that.

Comment: These are `slice`, not array !

Comment: Stuff the strings of the shorter slice into a map as the keys for O(1) lookup of existence and iterate the longer slice looking up the values in the map appending to the result set if found. Requires more memory than your approach. Tradeoffs as usual.

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: [Check if a value is in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30452518/1705598); and [How can I create an array that contains unique strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33207265/1705598); and [Efficient way to check IP in slice of IP addresses in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39249045/1705598); and [Finding Unique Items in a Go Slice or Array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34111576/1705598)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firstSlice := []string{"F8-E7-1E-14-AE-00", "F8-E7-1E-14-D0-30",
    "84-18-3A-2F-05-E0", "84-18-3A-2F-05-E8"}
secondSlice := []string{"F8-E7-1E-14-D0-30", "84-18-3A-2F-05-E8",
    "F8-E7-1E-54-AE-08"}

resultSlice := []string{}
checkMap := map[string]struct{}{}

for _, addr := range firstSlice {
    checkMap[addr] = struct{}{}
}
for _, addr := range secondSlice {
    if _, ok := checkMap[addr]; ok {
        resultSlice = append(resultSlice, addr)
    }
}

fmt.Println(resultSlice)
```

---

The output is what you want.

An empty struct takes no space in monery

What's more, always use camel in golang.

Comment: How is performance for large set of data using this..Is that reason to use map.

Comment: @SandunPriyanka The time complexity is O(n), which is much better than the one you posted at O(n^2). The only problem is that it will take more memory. Using empty struct can save some memory

Comment: Thanks for the help.