# Remove Adjacent Duplicates in string slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have a problem statement to `write an in-place function to eliminate the adjacent duplicates in a string slice.`

I came up with the following code

```
func main() {
    tempData := []string{"abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi"}
    removeAdjacentDuplicates(tempData)
    fmt.Println(tempData)
}

func removeAdjacentDuplicates(data []string) {
    for j := 1; j < len(data); {
        if data[j-1] == data[j] {
            data = append(data[:j], data[j+1:]...)
        } else {
            j++
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

The output is following

```
[abc def ghi]
[abc def ghi ghi ghi ghi]
```

My doubt is, if in the function, slice is modified, then in the calling function, why isn't the slice giving correct results?
Also, any article to understand the `slices` (and the underlying `array`) much better would be very helpful.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro and https://blog.golang.org/slices

Comment: Also, `data = append(data[:j], data[j+1:]...)` is copying a lot of data (the rest of the slice), which can ruin the performance. You can alter this a little and avoid it by appending single item in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The func removeAdjacentDuplicate takes the slice "as if" it is a reference to tempData

The capacity and length of tempData in the main() stays the same for the lifetime
of the program

In the removeAdjacentDuplicate func each time a dupe is found the final value of "ghi" is moved from the end to the end - 1.  So in the memory at the end of the
slice there are repeated "ghi"

When the control returns to the main, the program prints out the now modified
slice tempData.  Because it was passed in a similar way to a reference to the
function it is this memory that was modified.  The function call did not make a copy of the memory

You can see this behaviour by looking at the cap() and len() as the program runs

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        tempData := []string{"abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi"}
        removeAdjacentDuplicates(tempData)
        fmt.Println(tempData,cap(tempData),len(tempData))
}

func removeAdjacentDuplicates(data []string) {
        for j := 1; j < len(data); {
                if data[j-1] == data[j] {
                        data = append(data[:j], data[j+1:]...)
        fmt.Println(data,cap(data),len(data))
                } else {
                        j++
                }
        }
        fmt.Println(data, cap(data),len(data))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `removeAdjacentDuplicates` wants to mutate the slcie passed in argument. This is not really possible.

This function should return the new slice, just like `append` does.

```
func removeAdjacentDuplicates(data []string) []string{
    for j := 1; j < len(data); {
        if data[j-1] == data[j] {
            data = append(data[:j], data[j+1:]...)
        } else {
            j++
        }
    }
    return data
}
```

If you really want to mutate the argument, it is possible but you need to pass a pointer to a slice `*[]string`

Answer (score 0):

#### Go 1.18 and above

You can use [`slices.Compact`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Compact) exactly for this.

> Compact replaces consecutive runs of equal elements with a single copy. This is like the uniq command found on Unix. Compact modifies the contents of the slice s; it does not create a new slice.

```
func main() {
    data := []string{"abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi"}
    data = slices.Compact(data)
    fmt.Println(data) // [abc def ghi]
}
```

The package is `golang.org/x/exp/slices`, which is still experimental. If you don't want to import an `exp` package, you can copy the source:

```
func Compact[S ~[]E, E comparable](s S) S {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return s
    }
    i := 1
    last := s[0]
    for _, v := range s[1:] {
        if v != last {
            s[i] = v
            i++
            last = v
        }
    }
    return s[:i]
}
```

If the slice's elements aren't comparable, use [`slices.CompactFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#CompactFunc) which works the same but takes also a comparator function.

Comment: One tripwire with slices.Compact is that the elements needs to be sorted because it only removes adjacent duplicate entities. Luckily, you can easily just do ```slices.Sort(mySlice)``` before you do ```myslice = slices.Compact(mySlice)```. ```slices.Sort``` sorts the slice in place so it doesn't return anything, while ```slices.Compact``` does return the reduced slice. If you don't want to sort it, you can use the ```slices.CompactFunc``` to implement your own compact function to remove duplicates without reordering the content.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function:

```
func deleteAdjacentDuplicate(slice []string) []string {
    for i := 1; i < len(slice); i++ {
        if slice[i-1] == slice[i] {
            copy(slice[i:], slice[i+1:]) //copy [4] where there is [3, 4] => [4, 4]
            slice = slice[:len(slice)-1] //removes last element
            i-- //avoid advancing counter
        }
    }
    return slice
}
```